# MATLAB GUI executable windows application wont display

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, matlab-compiler

In MATLAB I have created an image recognition application that loads an image and then detects what currency it is. On MATLAB I have run the program thousands of times with the GUI displaying and everything working out fine within the MATLAB environment.

But when I turned the project into an executable via MATLAB the GUI wont display at all but it will still run in the background so I have to go to task manager to manually close the program. I have installed MATLAB Runtime for my PC.

I did a Test and created a simple GUI with just one button, converted that to an executable and it ran fine displaying the contents of the GUI. So I know there is nothing wrong with MATLAB, its just my code.

So I ran the image recognition executable through the command window and got this error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ActionData AbstractNamedUniqueID object with unique ID 'close-genome-desktop' and user-visible name 'Exit NGS Browser'. is already registered.
    at com.mathworks.mwswing.binding.KeyBindingManager.throwError(KeyBindingManager.java:623)
    at com.mathworks.mwswing.binding.KeyBindingManager.addAction(KeyBindingManager.java:201)
    at com.mathworks.mwswing.binding.KeyBindingManager.parseAndRegisterActions(KeyBindingManager.java:71)
    at com.mathworks.services.binding.MatlabKeyBindings.addActionFile(MatlabKeyBindings.java:666)
    at com.mathworks.services.binding.MatlabKeyBindings.readActionAndContextFilesFromOSGi(MatlabKeyBindings.java:639)
    at com.mathworks.services.binding.MatlabKeyBindings.<clinit>(MatlabKeyBindings.java:592)
    at com.mathworks.widgets.action.BaseAbstractAction.<init>(BaseAbstractAction.java:24)
    at com.mathworks.widgets.action.AbstractNewAction.<init>(AbstractNewAction.java:24)
    at com.mathworks.hg.peer.FiguresGroup$NewFigureAction.<init>(FiguresGroup.java:78)
    at com.mathworks.hg.peer.FiguresGroup.createToolBar(FiguresGroup.java:68)
    at com.mathworks.hg.peer.FiguresGroup.<init>(FiguresGroup.java:43)
    at com.mathworks.hg.peer.FiguresGroup.getInstance(FiguresGroup.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.mathworks.widgets.desk.DTGroup.createPropertyProvider(DTGroup.java:253)
    at com.mathworks.widgets.desk.DTGroup.getPropertyProvider(DTGroup.java:190)
    at com.mathworks.widgets.desk.DTOccupant.getProperty(DTOccupant.java:748)
    at com.mathworks.widgets.desk.DTOccupant.getToolstripTabs(DTOccupant.java:520)
    at com.mathworks.widgets.desk.DTGroup.add(DTGroup.java:345)
    at com.mathworks.widgets.desk.Desktop.addClient(Desktop.java:6569)
    at com.mathworks.widgets.desk.Desktop.addClient(Desktop.java:6536)
    at com.mathworks.widgets.desk.Desktop.addSingletons(Desktop.java:5603)
    at com.mathworks.mde.desk.MLDesktop.<init>(MLDesktop.java:554)
    at com.mathworks.mde.desk.MLDesktop.getInstance(MLDesktop.java:615)
    at com.mathworks.mde.desk.MLDesktopRegistrar.getDesktop(MLDesktopRegistrar.java:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.mathworks.mlservices.MLServices.getRegisteredService(MLServices.java:29)
    at com.mathworks.mlservices.MatlabDesktopServices.<clinit>(MatlabDesktopServices.java:14)
    at com.mathworks.hg.peer.FigureClientProxy.getMatlabDesktop(FigureClientProxy.java:504)
    at com.mathworks.hg.peer.FigureClientProxy.<init>(FigureClientProxy.java:92)
    at com.mathworks.hg.peer.HG2FigureClientProxy.<init>(HG2FigureClientProxy.java:20)
    at com.mathworks.hg.peer.FigureHG2Mediator.<init>(FigureHG2Mediator.java:43)
    at com.mathworks.hg.peer.HG2FigurePeer.createFigureClient(HG2FigurePeer.java:74)
    at com.mathworks.hg.peer.FigurePeer.doInitializePeer(FigurePeer.java:454)
    at com.mathworks.hg.peer.FigurePeer$2.run(FigurePeer.java:419)
    at com.mathworks.jmi.AWTUtilities$Invoker$5$1.run(AWTUtilities.java:591)
    at com.mathworks.mvm.context.ThreadContext$1.call(ThreadContext.java:76)
    at com.mathworks.mvm.context.ThreadContext.callWithContext(ThreadContext.java:105)
    at com.mathworks.mvm.context.ThreadContext.runWithContext(ThreadContext.java:73)
    at com.mathworks.mvm.context.MvmContext.runWithContext(MvmContext.java:107)
    at com.mathworks.jmi.AWTUtilities$Invoker$5.runWithOutput(AWTUtilities.java:588)
    at com.mathworks.jmi.AWTUtilities$Invoker$2.watchedRun(AWTUtilities.java:475)
    at com.mathworks.jmi.AWTUtilities$WatchedRunnable.run(AWTUtilities.java:436)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Warning: Unable to create com.mathworks.hg.peer.FiguresGroup, for details see
 C:\Users\ELECTR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\MATLABDesktopCreateError.log
```

And this is my main file that calls all my functions and has the GUI event action - Image.m

```
function varargout = Image(varargin)
% IMAGE MATLAB code for Image.fig
%      IMAGE, by itself, creates a new IMAGE or raises the existing
%      singleton*.
%
%      H = IMAGE returns the handle to a new IMAGE or the handle to
%      the existing singleton*.
%
%      IMAGE('CALLBACK',hObject,eventData,handles,...) calls the local
%      function named CALLBACK in IMAGE.M with the given input arguments.
%
%      IMAGE('Property','Value',...) creates a new IMAGE or raises the
%      existing singleton*.  Starting from the left, property value pairs are
%      applied to the GUI before Image_OpeningFcn gets called.  An
%      unrecognized property name or invalid value makes property application
%      stop.  All inputs are passed to Image_OpeningFcn via varargin.
%
%      *See GUI Options on GUIDE's Tools menu.  Choose "GUI allows only one
%      instance to run (singleton)".
%
% See also: GUIDE, GUIDATA, GUIHANDLES

% Edit the above text to modify the response to help Image

% Last Modified by GUIDE v2.5 14-May-2016 19:14:58

% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @Image_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @Image_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


% --- Executes just before Image is made visible.
function Image_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to Image (see VARARGIN)

% Choose default command line output for Image
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

% UIWAIT makes Image wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
% uiwait(handles.figure1);


% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = Image_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
% varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Get default command line output from handles structure
varargout{1} = handles.output;


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
global im im2
[path,user_cance]=imgetfile();
if user_cance
    msgbox(sprintf('Error'),'Error','Error');
    return
end
im=imread(path);
im=im2double(im); %converts to double
im2=im; %for backup process :)
axes(handles.axes1);
imshow(im);
currency = ClassImages(path)
set(handles.edit1,'String',currency)

% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton2.
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton3.
function pushbutton3_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton3 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton4.
function pushbutton4_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton4 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)


% --- Executes on slider movement.
function slider1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to slider1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'Value') returns position of slider
%        get(hObject,'Min') and get(hObject,'Max') to determine range of slider


% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function slider1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to slider1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

% Hint: slider controls usually have a light gray background.
if isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor',[.9 .9 .9]);
end



function edit1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to edit1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of edit1 as text
%        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of edit1 as a double


% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function edit1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to edit1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

% Hint: edit controls usually have a white background on Windows.
%       See ISPC and COMPUTER.
if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end
```

The only piece of code that I added to this was (I commented it for extra clarity)

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
global im im2 %Hold two images im-Main-Image im2-Second-Image
[path,user_cance]=imgetfile(); % Push button and store the path of the image in path
if user_cance
    msgbox(sprintf('Error'),'Error','Error'); % If Image is not found display error
    return
end
im=imread(path); %Read image and store in im
im=im2double(im); %converts to double
im2=im; %for backup process :)
axes(handles.axes1); % Display the image on the axes
imshow(im); %Show Image
currency = ClassImages(path) % Stores the currency of the image in currency
set(handles.edit1,'String',currency) %Sets  edit box in the GUI to the value of the currency
```

I have no idea whats wrong, it works fine when running it in MATLAB, but crashes when it becomes an executable application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I was able to solve it. Initially I was using MATLAB R2016a. And I was using an old function that MATLAB warned would be phased out in the next set of MATLAB applications. When I removed the old function and recompiled it into an executable it worked. So initially the MATLAB Runtime for R2016a didn't have that function in its library. But I needed that function in order for my application to work. So I downgraded to MATLAB R2015a and my executable worked with the old function included.